# How do I sort these arrays of objects in ascending order in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Here is my array of objects

```
Game[] gameConsoles = new Games[5];
// paramaters are name of the console and game ID
gameConsoles[0] = new Games("Playstation 4", 101);
gameConsoles[1] = new Games("Xbox 1", 108);
gameConsoles[2] = new Games("PS Vita", 110);
gameConsoles[3] = new Games("Wii U", 104);
gameConsoles[4] = new Games("3DS", 102);

for (int i = 0; i < gameConsoles.Length; i++)
{
    gameConsoles[i].display();
}
```

It will basically display all 5 objects in each message box but how do I make it so that it can display them based on the game ID order in ascending?

My sorting algorithm I used when I sorted a regular array of numbers.

```
public void ascendingOrder()
{
    // helper class
    double temp = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])
            {
                temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                numbers[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, if that involves the use of "=>" symbol then I won't use it.

Comment: Why not? Learning a bit of lambda syntax (that's the `=>`) and LINQ (which is a library of methods, like `OrderBy`) is well worth it. Or are you, for homework, required to implement an ordering algorithm?

Comment: @TimS. I thought my professor didn't let me but he actually accepted it so it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use use LINQ [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
foreach(var item in gameConsole.OrderBy(r=> r.GameID))
{
   item.display();
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to avoid using the => symbol? I don't think my teacher allows me.

Comment: @puretppc, its lambda expression, Do you have to implement your own custom logic for sorting ?

Comment: I did a sort algorithm using a nested loop one time. That's why I prefer to use code that may be understandable for me. I just dont know how to use one for a specific property in the array of objects.

Comment: @puretppc, update your question with what you have already tried for sorting and ask where you are stuck at. In your current question its not clear and not mentioned that you don't want to use LINQ

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from my other programs and got the ascending order code from a nested loop.

Comment: @puretppc, in your current code for sorting instead of `numbers` use `gameConsoles[i].GameID` to compare , try and see how it goes

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just give a +1 for your original answer. Sorry for wasting a little time from you but I just asked my professor and he let me use it.

Answer (score 4):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedDictionary<int, Game> gameConsoles = new SortedDictionary<int, Game>();

            gameConsoles.Add(101, new Game("Playstation 4", 101));
            gameConsoles.Add(108, new Game("Xbox 1", 108));
            gameConsoles.Add(110, new Game("PS Vita", 110));
            gameConsoles.Add(104, new Game("Wii U", 104));
            gameConsoles.Add(102, new Game("3DS", 102));

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Game> item in gameConsoles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Game
    {
        public Game(string name, int id)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Id: {0} Name: {1}", Id, Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three common ways to order items in .NET:

- Using LINQ (your comments suggest that this is not allowed for the purposes of your assignment)
- Implementing [`IComparable<Games>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `Games` class, or
- Providing an instance of [`IComparer<Games>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the `Sort` method.

Here is how you implement `IComparable<Games>`:

```
class Games : IComparable<Games> {
    public int CompareTo(Games other) {
        return GameId.CompareTo(other.GameId);
    }
}
```

Now your `Games` would sort based on `GameId`.

Here is how you use an external `IComparer<Games>`:

```
class CompareGamesOnId : IComparer<Games> {
    int Compare(Games a, Games b) {
        return a.GameId.CompareTo(b.GameId);
    }
}
```

You call [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
Array.Sort(games, new CompareGamesOnId());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a 1 liner for this. LINQ is good for operations which do not affect the set.

```
gameConsoles.OrderBy(gc => gc.GameID).ToList().ForEach(g => g.display());
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IComparable` on Games and use the .Sort method?[IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try LINQ without using the dreaded `=>` symbol, although of course, it is not recommended for simplicity purposes. However, this explains what exactly is `=>` doing,

```
foreach (var item in gameConsole.OrderBy(delegate(Game g) { return g.GameId; }))
{
    item.display();
}
```